# How to get a webservice's own endpoint in C#?

Tags: c#, web-services, url, endpoint

I have a C# webservice, as such:

```
namespace MyProject
{
  #region "Frontend"

  [WebService(Name="MyWebservice")]
  [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
  [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
  public class MyWsClass : System.Web.Services.WebService
  {
     private static readonly IRegisterer reg = new SelfRegisterInDatabase();

     private MyWsClass() 
     {
       // tell who I am to a database
       MyWsClass.reg.SelfRegister();
     }

     // A service I expose to the users
     [WebMethod]
     public object MyMethod(object in)
     {
       // do some work
       return new Object();
     }
  }

  #endregion

  #region "Backend"

  public interface IRegisterer
  {
    public void SelfRegister();
  }

  // Herein lies my question:
  public class SelfRegisterInDatabase : IRegisterer
  {
    private static volatile bool IsRegistered = false;

    public void SelfRegister()
    {
      if(!IsRegistered)
      {
        // Expecting something like: "http://THEHOST:THEPORT/MyWebservice.aspx?WSDL"
        // In principle, the variable part is "THEHOST:THEPORT".
        string EndpointUrl = 
"HOW_DO_I_GET_WEBSERVICE_ENDPOINT_URL_HERE???"
        ;

        // 1) open a Database connection;
        // 2) insert new entry for this EndpointUrl string if doesn't exist;
        // 3) and close DB connection
        SelfRegisterInDatabase.IsRegistered = true;
      }
      return;
    }
  }
  #endregion
}
```

I would like to know how can I dynamically read the webservice's own endpoint, so that I can have it register in a database (say, SQL Server -- the actual `INSERT`ing is not what I'm asking about here). Which method/configuration should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to get the entire endpoint String:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.RequestUri.OriginalString
```

You'll need

```
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
```

Comment: A couple of idiotic questions, for clarification:  1) That parameter read only works when invoked from a [WebService], so it won't work (for example) when invoked from outside a WebService class. Is this correct?  2) If it should be called from a [WebService] class, is it only restricted to a [WebMethod] or can it be invoked, say, in the [WebService] class constructor?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the complete endpoint address that was called (e.g.: http://your_webservice/your_resource/id/123):

```
string OriginalEndpoint = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.OriginalString;
```

If you don't want the resource part (e.g. just: http://your_webservice) you can replace the local part of the path with an empty string:

```
string ServiceEndpoint = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.OriginalString.Replace(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.LocalPath, "");
```

You must be `using System.Web.HttpContext`